# Assign custom category to block - Gutenberg - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Can we able to assign default(Like Advanced Heading) block in the new custom category?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Could you tell us a bit more about it?

Comment: Can you please review here in details: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/assign-custom-category-to-block